# find default key shortcuts in GTK

Tags: python, gtk3, gtk2

Is there a way to get the default key shortcuts for common operations in GTK2/GTK3.

I am specifically interested in finding the shortcuts for Copy.

In QT there is http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#standard-shortcuts
I guess there is something similar in GTK but I coulnd't find it.

I'm working on Python but any reference will help.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the standard reference for this would be the [GNOME Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/stable/index-info.html.en).

This has a section on [Keyboard Interaction](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/stable/input-keyboard.html.en), which amongst other things lists the various [Standard Application Shortcut Keys](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/stable/input-keyboard.html.en#standard-shortcuts).

For comparison with other platforms, there's also the [Table of Shortcut Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Comparison_of_keyboard_shortcuts) in Wikipedia.

Comment: I am not looking for a table, I am looking for a function that will return the appropiate shortcuts based on the OS and user preferences.

Comment: @fariza. I don't think there is a specific GTK api/enum for this: you just have to take the info from the HIG.